# I'm trying to call an imported function, however I'm not getting a return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, return-value

I've imported a function getFilm which is a fetch request to an API and to which I have tested in the console and returns a promise. However when I've imported and called it here in the app component, I don't get a promise back. How can I resolve this please?

```
searchOmdb() {
    return getFilm();
    // .then(filmDetail => {
    //   console.log(filmDetail);
    //   this.setState({ film: filmDetail });
    // });
  }
```

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please demonstrate how does `getFilm()` looks like, and make minimal reproducible example.